# How to create Spinner ArrayAdapter using xml layout but without pass R.arrays.xml id

Tags: android, android-spinner

I set the spinner list adapter items with

```
myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MyActivity.this, R.array.my_array.xml, R.layout.spinner_item);
```

Now I want to use an array created programmatically (not in xml)

```
String myArray[]={somethinggenerated};
```

if I try

```
myAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MyActivity.this, myArray, R.layout.spinner_item);
```

doesn't work because doesn't match with the method.

How could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creates a new ArrayAdapter from external resources. The content of the array is obtained through getTextArray(int).

```
 ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MyActivity.this, R.array.my_array.xml, R.layout.spinner_item);
```

In your case you have to use below way :-

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout,  myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arraylist instead and attach it to the adapter as follows:

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list1");
        list.add("list2");
        list.add("list3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```